# CSS specificity calculation and incorrect behavior in browsers

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

According to my understanding of CSS specificity calculations, the color of h1 below should be red, but the browsers show it in blue font. Any idea what I am missing?

```css
#contact h1 {color:blue;}         /* specificity: 0101 */
body#contact div p h1 {color:red;}  /* specificity: 0104 */
```

```html
<body id="contact">
    <div>
        <p>
            <h1>Example</h1>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put an `<h1>` tag inside a `<p>` tag. Browsers know this and correct it; if you inspect the markdown of a page with this code, you'll see the browser is automatically closing the `<p>` tag before the `<h1>` tag is opened. So the browser is actually presenting your code as:

```html
<body id="contact">
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And because of this, it means your `<h1>` is not actually a descendant of `<p>`. Therefore, your selector of `body#contact div p h1` doesn't affect anything.

See [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) for a list of what elements are allowed inside `<p>` elements.

Comment: Thank you. I referred to w3.org and indeed you cannot place any block-level elements inside p element.